# Does reducing the image dimensions before sending them to Language Models (LMs) significantly affect the processing time?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-recognition, image-processing

I am currently working on utilizing Language Models (LMs) to describe images in my project ([Search Engine for AI images](https://kazimir.ai/)). However, I am wondering about the efficiency of the process, particularly in terms of processing time. Before feeding images into the Language Models (I'm using [llava-13b](https://replicate.com/yorickvp/llava-13b)), I am considering reducing their dimensions. My rationale behind this is to potentially decrease the time needed to process each image.

Is this approach advisable? Does reducing the image dimensions before sending them to Language Models (LMs) significantly affect the processing time? Or would the reduction in image quality adversely impact the accuracy of the descriptions generated by the Language Models (LMs)?

I would appreciate any insights or experiences anyone has had with a similar scenario. Thank you!